# Identifying 6 pin SMD 23ALB7

Tags: surface-mount, laptop

I need some help identifying these SMD . 23ALB7  with 6 pins.

They are found on a laptop TOSHIBA SATELITE L650.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to trace the pin connections to get a better idea of what it could be. From the pictures it seems connected to power planes, so it is probably some type of protection diode array.

Comment: FETs, you have one thin conductor going to the gate.

Answer (score 1):

Vishay [Si1472DH](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73891/si1472dh.pdf) power MOSFET, 30V 60mΩ